# Get a List of Long values from a Map for a specific Key in Java

Tags: java

I have a Map: `Map<String, Object> data`
The content is:

```
{"id_list":["2147041","2155271","2155281"],
 "remoteHost":"127.0.0.1",
 "userId":"user",
 "agencyId":1}
```

I want to store in a Long List, all the values with `Key: id_list`
It would be:

`list:[2147041,2155271,2155281]` 
Is there a way to do that?
I've got:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(data.get("id_list") );
```

Comment: What is the return type of Map.get(), when the map is a Map<String, Object>? You need to consult the javadoc to know that. Is there, in the javadoc of ArrayList, a constructor accepting this type as argument? You need to consult the javadoc of ArrayList to know that (although the error message you get from the compiler also answers the question). What is the actual concrete type of the object stored for the  "id_list"? You should know that, since you're probably the one having put that value in the map. Tell us. If you don't, how about printing it: `data.get("id_list").getClass()`.

Comment: What is stopping you? You know that `id_list` is a list/array of `String` values, so you *know* that you have to loop through those values and parse them to `Long`. I see no attempt at doing that, so http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: data.get("id_list").getClass()  returns class: java.util.ArrayList

Comment: (List<Long>) ((List) data.get("id_list")).stream().map( it -> Long.parseLong((String) it) ).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: So, you have a List<String>: (`List<String> listOfStrings = (List<String>) map.get("id_list")`), that you want to transform into a List<Long>. How could you do that?

Comment: The list of strings in the example are string representations of long values. my answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the values in the collection of `id_list` are `String` objects, so you should be able to do it with a loop that performs conversions:

```
Iterable<String> idStrings = (Iterable<String>)data.get("id_list");
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (String id : idStrings) {
    list.add(Long.valueOf(id));
}
```

Comment: Hi, why don't use Stream for this.
`List<Long> list = ((List<String>)data.get("id_list")).Stream().map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

`new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(data.get("id_list")));`

Assuming that is an array in your hashMap. Otherwise you'd have to cast it as an `(Iterable<String>)data.get("id_list");` and add each String one by one.

Comment: 1. It's not an array. 2. Even if it was, get() returns an Object, so the result would be a list containing a single element, of type String[]. 3. The OP wants a List<Long>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.asList` to instantiate from that array

```
List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(data.get("id_list"));
```

or if you want a new ArrayList instead of just a genericl List

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(data.get("id_list")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If running on `Java 8 or later`, you may use a `BiFunction` for this:

```java
  

  private BiFunction<Map<String, Object>, String, List<Long>> convertToLong() {
    return (thatMap, targetKey) -> thatMap.get(targetKey).stream()
          .map(id -> Long.valueOf(id))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

```java
    // The call

    String targetKey = "id_list";
    // prepare the values of this accordingly.
    Map<String, Object> thatMap = new HashMap<>();

    List<Long> converted = convertToLong().apply(thatMap, targetKey)
    
    // Assumption for the output: your map contains the sample data provided here.
    System.out.println("converted: " + converted); //=> [2147041, 2155271, 2155281]
```